# Omitting an optional parameter, which is before another optional parameter in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to React, so please forgive me if I'm making a mistake :)

I'm using React router dom version 4.2.2.

I'm defining a path in my `BrowserRouter` like this :

```
<Route exact path="/my-base-url/myForm/:formMode/:templateID?/:ruleID?" component={MyFormComponent}/>
```

And referring in `MyFormComponent.jsx` as :

```
let formMode = this.props.match.params.formMode;    
let templateID = this.props.match.params.templateID;
let ruleID = this.props.match.params.ruleID;
```

My question is, In a case where `templateID` is not present, and **only** `ruleID` is present, Is there any possibility to omit the `templateID` and send only `ruleID`? (And how to read it?)

I found out that [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) makes this possible, but I would like to maintain the 'path parameters'.

Note that, the following are the possible scenarios for me :

```
formMode     CREATE    EDIT    DELETE
---------------------------------------
templateID    yes       no       no
ruleID        no        yes      yes
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a path like `/templateID/:templateID?/ruleID/:ruleID?`

With `/templateID/1/ruleID/1` you will have `{ params: { templateID:1, ruleID:1 }}`

With `/templateID/ruleID/1` you will have `{ params: { ruleID:1 }}`

[route tester](https://pshrmn.github.io/route-tester/#/)

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

why not simply add a second rule definition and stick it inside a `<Switch>`:

```
<Route exact path="/my-base-url/myForm/:formMode/:ruleID?" component={MyFormComponent}/>
```

please note that this assumes:

> /my-base-url/myform/2 -> ruleId
>
> /my-base-url/myform/1/2 -> templateId, ruleId

won't work as

> /my-base-url/myform/1 -> templateId with ruleId optional.

alternatively, you can use the `render={}` prop instead of the `component=` and compose what you want so you don't have to change the API of the form guy

```
<Route exact path="/my-base-url/myForm/:formMode/:templateID?/:ruleID?" 
    render={({match: { params }}) => params.templateId ? 
      <MyFormComponent templateId={params.templateId} : 
      <SomethingElse />
} />
```

Comment: I had an idea to use render={}, but it won't be suitable for the above mentioned requirement because I would have to put many short-hand if-else blocks to check whether the possible combinations of the two parameters can be there/not. Thanks for the answer anyhow :)